# Cloud Firestore emulator not running when using firebase serve method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've been trying to implement some Cloud Functions that get and post data from Cloud Firestore(I'm using postman). I want to test these locally, however I cannot get the Cloud Firestore emulator to run.

My index.js file

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");

admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let posts = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        posts.push({
          postId: doc.id,
          body: doc.data().body,
          userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
        });
      });
      return res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
  const newPost = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  };

  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("posts")
    .add(newPost)
    .then((doc) => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.log(err);
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I can get data when never i use firebase deploy method using postman.
result for firebase deploy method is response (status:200) [in postman]

However if i try firebase serve or firebase serve --only function . i get like this...

```
firebase serve

=== Serving from 'C:\Users\Yuvan M\Documents\Visual Studio Code\React\meme-zha\meeme-functions'...

!  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\Yuvan M\Documents\Visual Studio Code\React\meme-zha\meeme-functions\functions" for Cloud Functions...
+  functions[api]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/meeme-zha/us-central1/api)
```

in above code i can't get response like

```
i functions : preparing emulate function.
```

if i use this local address http://localhost:5000/meeme-zha/us-central1/api , this gives me the error like this...

```
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  External network resource requested!
```

I use firebase emulator:start - not working.I tried every solution that posted on internet for this kind of problem, also i followed the documentation . still i can't solve it.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself and format it so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Sorry for that!!! . I edited my pictures with actual code.

Comment: Check this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618725/firebase-serve-only-functions-vs-local-emulator-to-run-cloud-functions-locally/56620511#56620511

It seems it's been deprecated a long time ago.