# How to disable Firebase Storage emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-cli

When I start the emulators, the Storage emulator starts and is available at *localhost:9199*.
Then I access storage with the admin SDK in node.js with:

```
serviceAccountKey = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
const config = {
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey),
};
const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(config);
const storage = adminApp.storage();
```

Now storage points to the emulator, not the real service as before this emulator has been implemented.
How can I get access to the real service?
I have tried setting *projectId* and the env variable as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#admin_sdks), but it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so the way is simply to start all services but *storage* from the command line, and not from *firebase.json*, this way:

```
firebase emulators:start --only hosting,functions,firestore,auth,ui
```

Answer (score 2):

Running `firebase emulators:start` will start all services in an emulated state. If you want to talk to a production service, you can run `firebase serve`, *or* if you want some services emulated but not storage, you can run `firebase serve --only {services,to,emulate}` (eg, `firebase serve --only functions,hosting`. This would emulate functions and hosting, but any call to storage (or auth or other non-emulated services) would talk to the live Firebase environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would rather keep using *emulators* instead of *serve* because the latter [seems to be deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620511/6016470) and only emulates [hosting and functions triggered by HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620511/6016470). Also, up until *storage* has been added to the emulator suite, the command *emulators:start* only started the services listed in [firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite).